# Using if and else to decide between versions of website

Tags: php, if-statement

What i want to achieve is that a mobile user can have the option to view the pc version.
I want to pass on the information that the mobile user is viewing the pc version while on a mobile device. and to let the pc users just view the pc versions without any adjustments to get not redirected to the mobile page

```
    <?php
    // first line
    session_start();

    $t = $_GET['nm'];
    if ($t == 1) { // use 1 instead of "1"
        // store session data
        $_SESSION['nm'] = 1;
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                window.location = "http://www.gouda-info.nl/mobile";
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    $session = $_SESSION['nm'];
    if ($session == 1) { // use 1 instead of "1"

    ?>  
            **Site content (mobile users viewing pc version)**

    <?php 
}
else
{
?>
                **Site content (pc users view pc version)**
<?php
}
?>
```

When i try to view this page with http://www.gouda-info.nl/index.php?mn=1
it just gives me the normal pc version which is what i dont want if i have nm switched to '1'

hope anyone can help :)

Comment: You posted this 27 minutes ago. If you're THAT impatient and can't wait for an answer, then go somewhere else and HIRE someone to fix your code for you. Posting duplicates here will just make it that much less likely someone will be willing to help you.

Comment: this is whole different problem, what i try to do here is let the system chose if the user wants to view the desktop version while on a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Your link has a misspelling in the GET variable (mn => nm).

You also want to allow mobile users to view the PC version, but then you say when you pass a GET that would make the 'view pc version' if statement true, you shouldn't be getting that result.

Surely a better way would be to have a link on your page which would say e.g. Mobile Version - Click here to view desktop version, then set a variable for the users preference. That way you can wrap a redirect to the mobile version in a lookup to see if the users preference is set. If no preference is set, redirect to mobile version, if not continue running the code.

I also strongly advise separating your mobile and desktop versions of the site.